# Why apache cannot access location like /tmp/file.php

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

Recently i've installed apache on lubuntu, created file in  default /var/www/html
this file was requiring file from /tmp and it was not working.

I thought it is permission problem so i made 777 for file in tmp and made it executable. but this did not help.

It's strange becaouse on my home server running by Raspberry pi(raspbian) also with apache it's working like that out of the box,

I made sure that www-data user is capable of running this script correctly and it worked file was required correctly, but by http browser its not working.

Im i missing sth crucial for config in apache2.conf i've tried to ad this directory but nothing worked as expected.

Comment: Is Apache chrooted? What version of Ubuntu and Apache?

Comment: apache 2.4.29 ubuntu 18.04  i don't know how to check if it is chrooted

Comment: "It was not working" is not very helpful.  Check your Apache logs and edit your post to include the exact error message text.